# Upload Kaggle Dataset into Github

Tags: github, kaggle

Is there a way to upload a decompressed dataset from Kaggle into GitHub repository using Kaggle kernel?

Answer (score 1):

This is not recommended however there is access from Kaggle Kernel to the terminal by using <kbd>!</kbd> before the linux command.

Note: Please ensure the **internet** for the kernel is enabled

example :

```
!ls ../input
!git
```